# Laravel account details update

Tags: php, laravel

I am still getting to grips with the Laravel framework but something that should be simple is turning out to be a troublesome issue for me.

I have created a view inside `account/update.blade.php`

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('account-update-post') }}" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter handle" />
</p>
<p><input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook handle" /> 
<p><input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website url" /> 
<p><input type="text" name="about" placeholder="About me" /> 
<p><a href="{{ URL::route('account-change-password') }}">Change password</a></p>
<button class="button-default ">Update</button></p>
</form>
```

I have within `AccountController.php`

```
public function postUpdate(){
        $user           = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        $twitter    = Input::get('twitter');
        $facebook       = Input::get('facebook');

    return Redirect::route('account-update')
                ->with('global', 'Your account details could not be changed.');
}
```

I have created a Route:

```
/* Account update (POST) */
Route::post('/account/update', array(
    'as' => 'account-update-post',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@postUpdate'
));
```

Inside of my Models file I have `Update.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array('twitter', 'facebook', 'website', 'about';

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
```

And have setup my database with the relevant fields to accept this information. I do not need any validation on the fields but struggling as to why it isnt updating into the DB..

Comment: You are not calling update function of model. create update function and pass those values as array.

Comment: Please see amended code, still not working though...

Comment: You have to put update logic inside your postUpdate section. fillable just means that which values you want user to enter and values like created_at, deleted_at are part of hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working exactly as expected.

**Try this**

```
public function postUpdate() {

    # Update user in DB
    $user           = User::find(Auth::id());
    $user->twitter  = Input::get('twitter');
    $user->facebook = Input::get('facebook');
    $user-save();

    return Redirect::route('account-update')
                ->withGlobal('Your account has been successfully updated');

}
```

Comment: Also you don't need `protected $fillable = array('twitter', 'facebook', 'website', 'about';` in your User model since you are not using mass assignment creation.  Such as `User::create([]);` <- mass asignment

Answer (score 3):

> Updating A Retrieved Model

To update a model, you may retrieve it, change an attribute, and use the save method:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$user->twitter = Input::get('twitter');
$user->facebook = Input::get('facebook');
$user->save();
```

Then add your route to redirect to some page. See if that works. You can visit [Insert - Update - Delete Section](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete) from Laravel Docs

Comment: Ok so use the above code, when i hit update I get the following error: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Good answer. I'd just like to add one thing: the OP is using ``Auth::user()`` so you don't have to do ``User::find()``.

Comment: @JoelHinz Thanks and you are right, User::find is not needed if current user needs information update, but if he want to update some others data then he User::find is good, (but again not with Auth::user :D )

Comment: What implications does it have using Auth::user() over using User::find ?

Comment: Auth::user gives all the data which are marked fillabel from user model of logged in person and User::find means you are executing a query to fetch record from table define in user model, Well, both will give same output. Here difference is auth can only give data of current logged in user, but find will give you any data to request. (parameter is id in the user table)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the brackets.

`protected $fillable = array('twitter', 'facebook', 'website', 'about';`

should be

`protected $fillable = array('twitter', 'facebook', 'website', 'about');`